# Chrome 63 for IOS throws error on javascript variable declarations with LET

Tags: javascript, ios, cross-browser, progressive-web-apps

I have a PWA app coded with PHP and JS. And it is working well on Chrome, Firefox, Edge and Opera on windows desktop. I also tried on Chrome for android, and it working as expected also.

But when i tried it on `Ipad 2` with `Chrome 63`, i even couldn't login to my dashboard. When i used remote debugging, i realized that it throws error on Javascript variable declarations with `let`.

```
    let usr = $('#usrInput').val();
    let pwd = $('#pwdInput').val();
```

When i changed them to `var` i finally logged in to my dashboard.

But the problem is, there are a lot of variable declarations with `let`and it is hard and also not correct to do so. I also use a lot of **Javascript Libraries**, which i assume are full of `let` declarations.

I also do not know what kind of problems (apart from variable declarations) will still occur, even i changed all `let` to `var`.

Is it all about a compatibility issue? Or am i missing something else?

**UPDATE:** I changed `let` variable declarations to `var`. And finally could log in. Here is the initial and most important error log:

```
app.js:217 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'userChoice' of undefined
```

Which is triggered from:

```
    var promtEvent;
    window.addEventListener('beforeinstallprompt', (e) => {
        // Prevent Chrome 67 and earlier from automatically showing the prompt
        e.preventDefault();
        localStorage.setItem("uygulamaYuklendimi", false);
        btnAdd.removeAttribute("disabled", "");
        btnAdd.innerText = 'Uygulamayı Yükle';
        // Stash the event so it can be triggered later.
        promtEvent = e;
        // satinalmaKodu.style.display = 'block';
    });

   btnAdd.addEventListener('click', (e) => {
        // hide our user interface that shows our A2HS button
       $('#ayarlarModal').modal('hide');
       $('#satinalmaKodu').collapse();
        // Show the prompt
        if(promtEvent) promtEvent.prompt();
        // Wait for the user to respond to the prompt
        promtEvent.userChoice
            .then((choiceResult) => {
                promtEvent = null;
            });
   });
```

I believe, chrome can't initialize `beforeinstallprompt` event, which is probably because of compatibility issue.

Is there a way, or some kind of library which includes this behaviour?

> PS: **Javascript** is enabled on both **Safari** and **Chrome for IOS**.

Comment: Could you provide the logs?

Comment: @abielita I updated my question. Thx.